# Return the values of an object's properties using lambda expression (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, lambda, ienumerable

My ultimate goal is to produce an array of strings (`string[]`) from a class and its properties, using a single lambda query and reflection.

The first code block successfully produces an IEnumerable, while the second one does not. The difference is that the second block attempts to filter out properties that have an ***empty*** value. The only thing that I can conclude is that my syntax in the second is off somehow.

#### *Produces no Error:*

```
var x = from p in GetType()
                 .GetProperties()
                 .Where(n => n.Name.Contains("Anchors"))
        select p.GetValue(this));
```

#### *Produces Error:*

```
var x = from p in GetType()
                 .GetProperties()
                 .Where(n => n.Name.Contains("Anchors") & 
                     !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n.GetValue(this).ToString()))
        select p.GetValue(this));
```

How should I modify the second expression to filter out properties that have an ***null*** or ***empty*** value?

#### Here is the class:

```
public class DataPoint
{
    public string FI_Comments { get; set; }
    public string FI_DateInspected { get; set; }
    public string FI_Anchors1 { get; set; }
    public string FI_Anchors2 { get; set; }
    public string FI_Anchors3 { get; set; }
    public string FI_BoltsNuts1 { get; set; }
    public string FI_BoltsNuts2 { get; set; }
    public string FI_BoltsNuts3 { get; set; }
    public string FI_Conductors1 { get; set; }
    public string FI_Conductors2 { get; set; }
    public string FI_Conductors3 { get; set; }
    public string FI_Conductors4 { get; set; }
    public string FI_Conductors5 { get; set; }

    public string AnchorsData
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join("\n", from p in GetType()
                                              .GetProperties()
                                              .Where(n => n.Name.Contains("Anchors"))
                                     select p.GetValue(this, null));
        }
    }
```

One more detail on what I'm trying to achieve with the **get** action at the end - I simply want it to return all non-empty values of all the properties that have "Anchors" in the property name.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error? What is the definition of `GetType()` and what does it return?

Comment: It's a stackoverflow exception. And the Type is a user-created type. Will update original post to show full class.

Comment: When you have a question about a error you are getting you **must** include the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling yourself. Don't. Infinite recursion bad.

```
return string.Join("\n", from p in GetType()
                                  .GetProperties()
                                  .Where(n => n.Name.Contains("Anchors") 
                                           && n.Name != "AnchorsData")  //<-- Don't call yourself!
                         select p.GetValue(this, null));
```

Comment: Perfect fix John. Thanks! It’s so obvious after everyone’s comments and I feel stupid for missing it lol 

Answer (score 2):

- To process the `get` it will need to look up all things containing `Anchors`.

  - `AnchorsData` contains `Anchors` so has to process the `get`.

    - To process the `get` it will need to look up all things containing `Anchors`.

      - `AnchorsData` contains `Anchors` so has to process the `get`.

        - To process the `get` it will need to look up all things containing `Anchors`.

          - `AnchorsData` contains `Anchors` so has to process the `get`.

            - ...

Do you see the problem? That is why you are getting a stack overflow error.

Comment: Wow Scott way to make it obvious! Thanks for the answer and also the pointer above. I really appreciate the input and I will be sure to learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

```
...(n.GetValue(this).ToString())...
```

I thing here's the problem. After getting the value you try to call `.ToString()` even though there might be `null`. Try doing something like `?.ToString()`

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Unfortunately, however, I still get the stackoverflow exception even after checking for nulls.

Comment: Hm, then it might be a recursion. Since you are trying to get all property values of property with name containing Anchors. Maybe skip AnchorsData property?

Comment: I see my mistake now. I will simply change the name of the public prop to not contain the string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should skip the recursion (which should happen whether or not you are testing for null/empty properties) and only return non-empty:

```
    return string.Join("\n", from p in GetType()
                                       .GetProperties()
                                       .Where(n => n.Name != "AnchorsData" && n.Name.Contains("Anchors") && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(n.GetValue(this)?.ToString()))
                             select p.GetValue(this));
```